# How are base pointers able to know the memory location of base members in a derived class instance?

Tags: c++, inheritance, compiler-construction, runtime

Suppose the following code with basic structures

```
struct A {int aMember};
struct B {bool bMember};
struct C {double cMember};
struct BA : B, A {};
struct CB : C, B {} ;

void test(B *base) {
    bool retrieved = base->bMember;
}
```

Here the test function is able to be passed a pointer to an instance of B, BA, or CB. How is the retrieval of the base class member "bMember" achieved in low-level terms? Presumably the member can't be guaranteed to be located at a given offset from the passed objects addressee for every derived type. In short, how is it "known" where the slice of B's members are located for any given derived type? Is this achieved at run-time with some sort of meta-data associated with objects and classes utilizing inheritance?

I'm terribly sorry if there's a simple explanation already posted. I just didn't know how to phrase my search to return a relevant answer.

Thankyou!

Comment: https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/classes-and-objects#layout-obj  This might help.

Comment: Because they are base pointers. They point to the base object. What's in the derived object is utterly irrelevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A given member of `B` is always at the same offset from `base`, because `base` is a `B*`.

The piece of the puzzle I think you're missing is that `test` isn't passed the address of the object itself when you're passing a `BA*` or a `CB*`.
Instead, it's passed the address of their respective *subobjects* of type `B`.

Example using your classes:

```
void test(B *base) {
    std::cout << "test got " << base << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    BA ba;
    CB cb;
    std::cout << "&ba: " << &ba << std::endl;
    std::cout << "ba's B subobject: " << static_cast<B*>(&ba) << std::endl;
    test(&ba);
    std::cout << "&cb: " << &cb << std::endl;
    std::cout << "cb's B subobject: " << static_cast<B*>(&cb) << std::endl;
    test(&cb);
}
```

For me, this printed

```
&ba: 0x28cc78
ba's B subobject: 0x28cc78
test got 0x28cc78
&cb: 0x28cc68
cb's B subobject: 0x28cc70
test got 0x28cc70
```

Both calls to `test` pass the `B` subobject to the function, and every `B` object looks the same, so `test` doesn't need to care about the other classes at all.

Note that `ba` and `ba`'s `B` subobject are in the same place; this particular implementation arranges subobject in the order they're specified in the inheritance list, and the first one is located first in the derived object.
(This isn't mandated by the standard, but it's a very common layout.)

Comment: Thank-you, that was exactly the piece of the puzzle I was missing! The code demonstration really helped consolidate this.

Answer (score 1):

`test` must be called with an argument of type `B*`. The compiler knows that even if it can't see the definition of `test` because C++ requires a function to be declared in any translation unit which references it.

C++ allows you to call `test` with a pointer to a `CB` precisely because it knows how to *convert* a `CB*` to a `B*`.

If the structures do not have virtual members, the conversion is normally extremely simple. The `CB` object will contain a `B` object at some offset. To convert a `CB*` to a `B*`, it is only necessary to add this offset. `test` doesn't need to know that the argument was converted, and it does not even need to know that `CB` even exists.

If there are virtual functions, things are slightly more complicated. In principle, the compiler still adjusts the `CB*` in the same way, but that is not sufficient to find the correct virtual functions at run time.

Although there are various ways to implement virtual functions and the C++ standard does not specify or even recommend a solution, the basic strategy is to include a pointer to a "vtable" in the object with virtual functions. The vtable is an sequence of function pointers for the virtual functions implemented by the actual object. Thus, the `B` object inside the `CB` object would have a vtable pointer to the virtual functions defined by `CB`. These functions must be called with `this` pointing to the actual `CB` object, so the vtable or the `B` object must also contain enough information to derive the `CB"`  from the `B*`at runtime. One possible solution is to store the adjustment (which will be subtracted from the `B*`), but there are a variety of other possibilities, with different advantages and disadvantages.

Comment: Thank-you for that response, I hadn't even thought of how other polymorphic behavior like virtual functions were implemented :)

Answer (score 0):

The standard doesn't define it.
The actual memory layout usually depends on the chosen ABI.
As an example, one of them is the [Itanium ABI](https://mentorembedded.github.io/cxx-abi/abi.html).
From the introduction:

> Application Binary Interface for C++ programs, that is, the object code interfaces between user C++ code and the implementation-provided system and libraries.
>   This includes the memory layout for C++ data objects, including both predefined and user-defined data types, as well as internal compiler generated objects such as virtual tables. It also includes function calling interfaces, exception handling interfaces, global naming, and various object code conventions.

[Here](https://mentorembedded.github.io/cxx-abi/abi.html#layout) is the section that rules on memory layout.